# Get current executing stored procedure name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, information-schema

I need a log for the stored procedures i have written in MySQL.
I know this is available in MS SQL Server as @@procid.

What is the equivalent in MySQL?

I'm going to use a timestamp, connection_id, database().

How can i get the name of the sp i am executing?
How about the sp that called me?

thanks,
adam

Comment: Try `CALL procedureName`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a procedure name as an IN parameter into called procedures, and log this information from these procedures.

For example -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN proc_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO proc_log VALUES('procedure1', proc_name, NOW());
END$$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure2(IN proc_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO proc_log VALUES('procedure2', proc_name, NOW());
  CALL procedure1('procedure2');
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL procedure2(NULL);

SELECT * FROM proc_log;
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| proc_name  | call_proc_name | call_ts             |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| procedure2 | NULL           | 2012-07-30 16:17:53 |
| procedure1 | procedure2     | 2012-07-30 16:17:53 |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: understood, but you would still need to pass 'prcodure2' as as hard-coded string. i want a system function that will return the name of the proc from which i am running, similar to connection_id() or database() or now()

Comment: the goal is to get this info without any hardcoding

Comment: I understand that it is better to use server's logic, but I have not found such functions in MySQL, and suggested this way.